# Wso2 response soapenv:Envelope was missed

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am using Wso2 EI 7.1.0, I implemented case like EI will get soap request that request will convert to json request then it will send to endpoint, from the endpoint EI will get json response that will convert to soap message again before responded to client. So here

**Expected Response:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
<message>
<response>success</response>
</message>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

> 

**Getting Response:**

```
<message>
<response>success</response>
</message>
```

Here soap tags are missing , So please update.

Thanks,

Ajay Babu Maguluri.

Comment: What is the Content-Type of the response that you are getting out from the EI? Is it `text/xml` or `application/xml`? Can you try changing the `messageType` to `application/xml` and verify it?

Comment: I did that still same issue here client I am checking from postman.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Issue was fixed when adding <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/soap+xml"/>

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are sending WSO2 a request with Content-Type `application/xml` (implying plain XML) So it will respond with a plain xml message without Soap envelope. In Postman try to set the content-type to `text/xml`.

Comment: I did that same issue, it was printing with Soap envelope in log which kept before respond.

Comment: Issue was fixed when adding <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/soap+xml"/>

Comment: Well this will also work, but note that by using messageType 'application/soap+xml' you manually set the response to SOAP 1.2. Normally it is better to let WSO2 figure this out based on the request.